# Windows API: Hide a button which is not a child window

Tags: windows, api, button, handle, spy++

I have a program, where I need to disable a specific button on toolbar. "Save" on the Adobe Reader control.

I know it's possible to hide a control by locating its window handle.

Using Spy++, I found the required toolbar. It has buttons and text fields. Although text fields are child windows of the toolbar, buttons aren't windows at all!

How to proceed in that case? Is there a way to hide such buttons? I tried locating them using relative position from the toolbar and displaying something on top, but it's sections can be repositioned manually by user.

Comment: You've fallen into the trap of thinking you the programmer own the user's computer as long as your program is (installed/running/etc./pick one).  This is incorrect.  The user owns the user's computer.  It's up to them whether or not they use the Save function of Adobe Reader, if you try to take away that choice this is a battle you will lose.

Comment: I'm not trying to restrict user's ability to save in Adobe Reader. It's about my own application, which uses Adobe Reader component to display protected content. And the point is to make it read-only.

Answer (score 1):

You should send a [TB_ENABLEBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787311(VS.85).aspx) to the toolbar

Comment: Lior, thanks for your answer. I can see wParam is a "Command identifier", where can I find it?

Comment: The value is assigned when adding the button to the toolbar. To discover this value, spy for toolbar notifications (NM_CLICK i presume).

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760435(v=VS.85).aspx for a list of all toolbar notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have the hwindow of the toolbar, you could iterate through all the buttons of the toolbar (position based, use [TB_BUTTONCOUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787297(v=VS.85).aspx) for number of buttons), use [TB_GETBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787319(v=VS.85).aspx) message to get the current command ID, then [TB_GETBUTTONTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787325(v=VS.85).aspx) (with the command id) to get the caption of the button. Then use [TB_ENABLEBUTTON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787311(v=VS.85).aspx) for the button with the caption you search.

Comment: The buttons have icons and no captions. Maybe I can find it by the number? And how to iterate through buttons of the toolbar? Which function should I use?

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried  Dim count As IntPtr = SendMessage(toolbarHandle, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) with a handler obtained from Spy++, and the result is always "Invalid Windows Handle"